# How to enable 'constructor-tearoffs' feature?

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, types

When I try to get the type of a class with generic

```
class Dummy<T> {
  T? value;
}

void main() {
  Type t = Dummy<int>;
}
```

I get this error:

> This requires the 'constructor-tearoffs' language feature to be enabled.
> Try updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 2.14.0 or higher, and running 'pub get'.

My pubspec.yaml containes the right SDK version, and I run already flutter clean and flutter pub get

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.14.4 <3.0.0"
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: what's the output from flutter --version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructor tearoffs are not going to help you accomplish this. The only approach I'm aware of that could work here is to use a `typedef` assigned to `Dummy<Int>` and assign `t` to that.

```dart
class Dummy<T> {
  T? value;
}

typedef DummyInt = Dummy<int>;

void main() {
  Type t = DummyInt;
}
```

---

For anyone who actually does want to enable constructor tearoffs see the documentation on [experimental flags](https://dart.dev/tools/experiment-flags). Use the flag `constructor-tearoffs` either by passing it in as a command line argument like `dart --enable-experiment=constructor-tearoffs bin/your_program.dart` or by configuring it in your `analysis_options.yaml` file or Visual Studio Code settings as described in the link.

---

UPDATE: As of [Dart 2.15](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-15-7e7a598e508a), constructor tear-offs have been added to the language, and you no longer need to use an experimental flag.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question... how to enable constructor-tearoffs?

Comment: @obe I have updated my response with information on how to enable constructor tear-offs.